# Execute powershell command using python

Tags: python, powershell

I want to execute power-shell command using my python script to find windows RDP event detail but it's not working.it shown error:

> 'C:\Windows\System32\powershell.exe' is an internal or external
>   command, It is not recognized as an operable program or batch file.

PowerShell command:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName "Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager/Operational" | Where-Object {$_.ID -eq "1149"}
```

Here is my python code:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call('C:\Windows\System32\powershell.exe Get-WinEvent -LogName "Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager/Operational" | Where-Object {$_.ID -eq "1149"}', shell=True)
```

Comment: Are u getting any error, please include that in the post.

Comment: Please edit the post and describe with more details what "it's not working" means. Do you get an error message? What does it say? (No images, but text.) No results at all? Wrong results? Something else, what?

Comment: Please try prepending `r` to the argument string. subprocess.call(r'C:\Windows\System32\powershell.exe Get-WinEvent -LogName "Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager/Operational" | Where-Object {$_.ID -eq "1149"}', shell=True)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using PowerShell, You can use [pywin32 module](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) to get the Windows events.

If there is no specific reason to use PowerShell then you can achieve it by using following code snippet

```
import win32evtlog # install pywin32 module

server = 'localhost' # target computer to get event logs
logtype = 'Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager' # 'Application' # 'Security'
hand = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(server,logtype)
flags = win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_BACKWARDS_READ|win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ
total = win32evtlog.GetNumberOfEventLogRecords(hand)

while True:
    events = win32evtlog.ReadEventLog(hand, flags,0)
    if events:
        for event in events:
            if "Microsoft-Windows-Terminal-Services-RemoteConnectionManager" in event.SourceName: 
                print ('Event Category:', event.EventCategory)
                print ('Time Generated:', event.TimeGenerated)
                print ('Source Name:', event.SourceName)
                print ('Event ID:', event.EventID)
                print ('Event Type:', event.EventType)
                data = event.StringInserts
                if data:
                    print ('Event Data:')
                    for msg in data:
                        print (msg)
                print
```

Comment: But  i couldn't get Microsoft-Windows-Terminal-Services-RemoteConnectionManager source using this code so it's event list  is not displaying.

Comment: I just provided way to get event logs using Python. Play around with the log type to get the desired output.